# Me da un NullPointer un ImageView que tengo bien definido

Tags: java, android

Me está dando un **NullPointer** esta línea, y no entiendo porqué... Creo que lo tengo todo bien, y sí sé lo que es un **NullPointer** y cómo arreglarlo. Pero aquí no sé porqué me lo está dando.

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_chat_black);
```

La duplicada no me ha ayudado, que ya sé lo que es un NullPointer.

Lo tengo así como pueden ver abajo y también he intentado solucionarlo de otra forma que también pueden observar más abajo.

Podría alguien ayudarme, sigo con el mismo problema ya varias semanas y no sé arreglarlo. Aunque obtengo el resultado correcto, me da un **NullPointer** y la página se congela antes de volverme a la página Home. Quiero que no me de el **NullPointer** y que fuera todo más suave.

Ninguna respuesta me ha ayudado todavía.

**CommentAdapter***

```
public class CommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Comment> mComment;
    private String postid;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public CommentAdapter(Context mContext, List<Comment> mComment, String postid) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mComment = mComment;
        this.postid = postid;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.comment_item, parent, false);
        return new CommentAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final Comment comment = mComment.get(position);

        holder.comment.setText(comment.getComment());
        getUserInfo(holder.image_profile, holder.username, comment.getPublisher());

holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {
                if (comment.getPublisher().equals(mFirebaseUser.getUid())) {

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Do you want to delete this comment?");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments").child(postid).child(comment.getCommentid())
                                            .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.commentPost);
              ---------------------------->     imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_chat_black);
                                                imageView.setTag("comment");
                                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Your comment has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mComment != null) {
            return mComment.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView image_profile;
        public TextView username, comment;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
            comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        }
    }
```

**Tambien he intentado solucionarlo así**

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView image_profile, imageView;
    public TextView username, comment;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentPost);
    }
}
```

**post_item**

```
               <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/commentPost"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/like"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_hollow" />
```

Comment: Si la duplicada no soluciona tu problema, por favor aclara mejor de donde viene cada cosa para poder ayudarte

Comment: Lo correcto es realizarlo con el ViewHolder pero debes obtener la referencia en tu mètodo onBindViewHolder() como holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_chat_black); solo asegura tambien que el ImageView se encuentra en comment_item.xml

Comment: @gbianchi sé que es un NullPointer. No tiene la respuesta que busco. He actualizado la pregunta para daros más información sobre el problema.

Comment: @Jorgesys pues, he intentado hacerlo así pero sigue dándome el NullPointer...

Comment: El imageView con id commentPost  debe encontrarse en comment_item.xml

Comment: @Jorgesys comment_item.xml? No tengo un comment_item.xml... Solo un post_item.xml

Comment: Pues lo estas cargando aqui: View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.comment_item, parent, false);

Comment: @Jorgesys lo que pasa es que en mi comment_item.xml borro el comentario y al hacerlo el icono el ImageView lo tengo en mi post_item.xml y al borrar el comentario tiene que cambiarse el icono del borde amarillo al borde negro en el post_item.xml. Cómo puedo hacerlo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104240/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-johnnnn).

Comment: @Jorgesys qué pasa tío, sigo teniendo el mismo problema con el icono que no se cambia al borrar los comentarios. Me podrías echar una mano? Hablamos en el chat si quieres

Comment: Pensé ya lo habías resuelto, ¿no te dio solución el usuario Andrespenginer?

Comment: @Jorgesys Sigue sin funcionar. Lo único que llega más o menos cerca a la solución es como lo tengo yo el código que he añadido en CommentAdapter que señalo con la flecha arriba, pero sigue dándome el NullPointer. Es decir que funciona, pero la página en plan se queda allí cargándose y luego queda todo bien, pero quiero que fuera todo mejor sin el NullPointer. Cuando intento escribir el código en PostAdapter no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Esta parte esta bien:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView image_profile, imageView;
    public TextView username, comment;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentPost);
    }
}
```

El detalle esta aqui cuando lo llamas:

```
@Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
   ELIMINA ESTO ------>                         imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.commentPost);
      ESTA PARTE INICIANIZALA CON "HOLDER"      holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_chat_black);
                                                holder.imageView.setTag("comment");
                                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Your comment has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
```

Comment: Intenté a hacerlo así como tú dices pero no funciona. El problema es que en ```CommentAdapter.java``` borro el comentario, pero el icono tiene que cambiarse en ```PostAdapter.java``` que es otra página, por lo que no me está funcionando. El problema es que el inflater lo tengo en ```View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.comment_item, parent, false);```, pero tiene que cambiarse en ```View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);```. Cómo lo hago?

Comment: Cómo puedo hacer porque si borro el comentario se vuelve a cargar la página y todo queda bien, pero me da un nullpointer porque son dos layouts distintas. comment_item para los comentarios y luego post_item para el icono que tiene que cambiarse al borrar el comentario. Me ayudas?